# aligning in same line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to make the the text box and the the form fields to align in same line...
i gave display inline but its not working...
providing my code below....
how to fix it...
text field is one line below the buttons....

http://jsfiddle.net/S9PYV/embedded/result/

```
<div class="bs-docs-example" id="notesDocumentsOuterDF">        
    <div class="documents-make-container">
        <!--<div class="insert-items-container">
            <label for="idName">Name</label>
            <input id="idName" type="text" name="name" value="" required="required" />
        </div>-->

        <div class="insert-items-container">
            <select class="greenButton">
                <option value="volvo">Create</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>

            <select class="greenButton">
                <option value="volvo">Email|Access</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>

            <input type="submit" class="greenButton" value="Add Contacts">
        </div>

        <div class="insert-items-container" style="float: right;">
            <!--<label for="idImageUpload">Image</label>-->
            <input type="file" name="file" id="idImageUpload" class="file" size="40">
            <div id="fakefile" class="fakefile">
                <input type="text" class="fakeinput">
                <img src="/images/icons/search.png">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--<div class="insert-items-container">
            <label for="idContactSel">Contacts List</label>
            <select id="idContactSel" name="contactselect">
                <option value="">select email to share </option>
            </select>                               
            <input id="shareListBtn" class="greenButton" type="button" value="Share List" alt="sharelist">
            <input id="contactListBtn" class="greenButton" type="button" value="Contacts List" alt="contactlist">
            <input id="AddContactBtn" class="greenButton" type="button" value="Add Contacts" alt="addcontacts">
        </div>-->

        <!--<div class="insert-items-container">
            <label for="idShareList">Share List</label>
            <div id="idShareList" class="email-selected-container">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="documentsListHeading" role="row">
                            <th width="100px;">name</th>
                            <th width="180px;">Email</th>
                            <th>Permission</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <!-- share list -->
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Gah, jsFiddle is down (for me at least). Is that all your code or is there any CSS or JavaScript too? If so, please update your question with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `insert-items-container` has 100% width (as default divs do) so it's filling the whole line. You can solve this either by putting the text box in the same `insert-items-container` with the other form fields, or by setting all `insert-items-container`s to `float: left`